# Navigate to a HTML localfile by the <a> balise in a QWebView

Tags: html, qt

I have a `QWebview`that I use to display local HTML files. I want to use the `<a>` tag to go to another file. I tried it but it doesn't work, I look for on the web but nothing worked. So for now I have this :

`Go to file - <a href="my/path/file.html">File Name</a><br />`

to set my link and then I put this in my HTML file and set it in my `QWebView`to display it. But when I click it it doesn't work.

Thanks

***EDIT I just try with a website :

`Go to file - <a href="http://www.google.ca">File Name</a><br />`

and it worked

Comment: I can't see any reason why that wouldn't work... Two things to check: 1) Are you certain that the relative path you're using is correct? Try simplifying the situation by linking to a file in the same folder as you first. 2) If you've taken code from elsewhere, check that `QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls` hasn't been disabled.

Comment: I'm sure the path is ok...I tried to do this : `QWebSettings * t = this->settings();
    t->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, true);` but it doesn't work neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do that, it's a little "longer" but, for me, it is even better because I can manage the `url` as I need :

`this->page()->setLinkDelegationPolicy(QWebPage::DelegateAllLinks);`

With that, I set the Link delegation propriety, I make it send the signal

`linkClicked(QUrl)`

every time a link is clicked. So I just have to connect it to a `slot`. That way, I receive the `href` of the clicked link. So it is  now easy to look in the `href`the file that I need because the `href`looks like that :

`qrc:/my/path/file.html`

qrc: is for local file, but whatever I can now the file to display!